# Making perl process to dump core instead of directly exiting from the process

Tags: perl, signals, coredump

In my Perl script (which runs as daemon), I accidentally tried to access an array element (which is also an array) that was not defined before. My script is exiting at this point but is not creating a core dump. Is it possible to dump core in this case? I tried killing my Perl process by `kill -6` command, the core dump gets generated in this case. But I want to generate a core dump in every instance when we exit unexpectedly from the script.

```
my @array = ();
my @a;
@a = @{$array[1]};
```

Comment: Accesing undefined array element doesn't exit in Perl: `perl -e 'print $arr[20]; print "still here"'`

Comment: Still no error for me.

Comment: "dump core" is not usually one of the steps in debugging a perl script.

Comment: One way to always get something is to put it in the `END` block.  It runs at every `die` or `exit`. But it may not be specific enough. Another way is to "protect" against errors as you code along -- use careful error checking.  Then, you can get very specific information.  Or, override the `die` but providing a hook (subroutine) for `$SIG{__DIE__}` "signal". See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42183690/4653379) for a debugger that fires off on any `die`, in a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead generate a core dump or something similar, I would recommended you log messages in your script and do some checks specially when you are trying to access something that does not exists.

[Using a source level debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips.html#Using-a-source-level-debugger) as suggested in perldoc are for some rare cases:

> If the debugging output of -D doesn't help you, it's time to step
>   through perl's execution with a source-level debugger.
>
> We'll use gdb for our examples here; the principles will apply to
>   any debugger (many vendors call their debugger dbx ), but check the
>   manual of the one you're using.

Trying to access a position of an array that does not exists can be avoided by using `if` and `else` for example:

```
my $wanted_position = 2;

if ( $wanted_position >= @array )
{

    #log a possible error
    #Do something else
}

@a = @{$array[$wanted_position]};
```

You can handle [signals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) inside your script also.

> Perl uses a simple signal handling model: the %SIG hash contains names
>   or references of user-installed signal handlers. These handlers will
>   be called with an argument which is the name of the signal that
>   triggered it. A signal may be generated intentionally from a
>   particular keyboard sequence like control-C or control-Z, sent to you
>   from another process, or triggered automatically by the kernel when
>   special events transpire, like a child process exiting, your own
>   process running out of stack space, or hitting a process file-size
>   limit.

Example:

```
 $SIG{DIE} = sub { #dump code here };
```