# Print stack trace when "Can't locate object method x via package y" (Perl)

Tags: perl, debugging

Chances are I invoke method x on an object of the wrong type, but it's way down in my call stack, so it's not obvious.

So: is there a way of always printing a full stack trace when this error occurs?

Comment: Simplest: add `use Carp::Always;` or run with `perl -MCarp::Always script` ... is that good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To always print a full stack trace add `use Carp::Always;` or run the program with

```
perl -MCarp::Always script
```

or, with bash

```
PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always script
```

what sets up the [`PERL5OPT` environment variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT) and runs the (executable) `script`. For one, this allows the shebang (`#!`) line in the `script` to decide which interpreter is used. If you `export` it (say in the shell configuration file), `export PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always`, then it will be used by all Perl scripts in that shell. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

To fine-tune which particular exceptions get more attention add the `$SIG{__DIE__}` hook

```
use Carp;

BEGIN { 
    $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { 
        confess @_ if $_[0] =~ /Can't locate object method/;  #'
    };  
};
```

and after the hook returns "*... the exception processing continues as it would have in the absence of the hook, unless ...*", see [%SIG in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG).  The code above `die`s normally on other errors.

Thus here you can change what happens as the `die` is thrown, with code run right before it goes. For example, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183690/4653379) for how to get all lexicals for each frame in the call stack.

Messing with this can get tricky so please read up on it. See links in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520365/4653379), for instance.

Comment: Not quite. I recommended `PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always script` There's no reason to make it apply to more than just that one script as the longer `export PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always` + `script` might accidentally do.

Comment: @ikegami  Heh ...  I use tcsh and didn't think that one can run a line just like that in bash (so I thought that you were referring to exporting it).  Updated.Thank you, again (and again)

Answer (score 1):

The [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) module which ships with Perl can be used to generate stack traces.

Carp provide replacements for `warn` and `die` which can be used either to simply bump the offending file and line number 1 level back up the call stack or to produce a stack trace.

In your case it sounds like you're not actually calling `die` - that's happening as a result of attempting to call a non-existent method.  For this circumstance you can use Carp's 'verbose' mode to force a stack trace globally.  There are a number of ways to enable verbose mode.  It can be done via the environment, from the command line used to invoke Perl or from inside your script:

```
use Carp 'verbose';
```