# How to provide more context for die-handler?

Tags: perl, exception

I'd like to have more context in error messages in cases some function has to `die`. In some situations I can provide it, in others I can't find a good way. For example, using the `RaiseError` option in connection to Postgres I get exceptions on every failure, but I can't provide more context into those errors. I have tried to use `die`-handler, but I can't figure out a sane way to include arguments for called subroutine, at least:

```
try {
  x( 'y' );
} catch {
  say "CATCHED error: $_";
};

sub _die_handler {
  my @caller = caller(1);
  say "@caller"; # how to access @_ for this frame 
  die @_;
}

sub x {
 local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&_die_handler;
 die;
}
```

How could I see in the example above, that `x` was called with 'y' as an argument?

If I have not modified `@_` in my subroutine, could I access it from my `_die_handler`? Or could I provide some data to the handler beforehand?

Two options I see now:

- through some global variable, which I always populate with needed data beforehand in case there may occur some error
- using objects, with die_handler-method in it

Better ways to do it?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991317/4653379) for getting stacktraces ... (there is a lot more on that out there) Something like that?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183690/4653379) for a way to walk the stack and get lexicals in the frames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not certain what "context" you want, but [Carp](https://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) is our friend here.

For one, by including `use Carp::Always;` we get the full stack backtrace printed on all errors.

If you'd rather be selective, the simplest thing is to directly use a suitable `Carp` routine

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Carp;

eval { my $y = 10;  x($y) };
if ($@) {
    print "eval: $@";
    # print/log else as wanted, recover and proceed or exit
}

say "done";

sub x {
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::confess;
    # ...
    my $bad_math = $_[0] / 0;
}
```

The `Carp::confess` dies, with a full stack backtrace, but in your example that `die` is caught by the `eval`.  By die-ing via `confess` and catching the exception you get the "call context" from `confess` but also retain control to proceed as you wish in the `eval` "catch."

This prints

```
eval: Illegal division by zero at error_context.pl line 18.
 at error_context.pl line 18.
        main::x(10) called at error_context.pl line 7
        eval {...} called at error_context.pl line 7
done
```

Without `eval` the program would terminate (unless there's an `eval` further up the stack) but we'd still get the full backtrace of the call. There are routines in `Carp` which don't die, and among them `cluck` also prints backtrace.

For a more custom handling use the `$SIG{__DIE__}` hook. A little snag with `Carp` is that the routine with backtrace which doesn't die, `cluck`, just prints to `STDERR` stream; we can't easily get that message to build it up further. The trace used to be in `longmess` but is not anymore and I don't think that one can get the stacktrace from `Carp` without `die`-ing.

Then use `confess`, which returns the trace, and wrap the call with `eval`

```
sub _die_handler {
    my $other_info = '...';
    Carp::confess($other_info . "\n" . $_[0]);
}
...
sub x { 
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&_die_handler;
    ...
}
...
eval { x() };
if ($@) { ... }  #-->  confess's trace with $other_info prepended
```

so as you handle its `die` the whole message is then in `$@` in your `eval`. For this to work you still need that `eval`.

If you'd rather be able to handle the exception completely in the hook see [Devel::StackTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::StackTrace)

```
use Devel::StackTrace;

sub _die_handler {
    my $trace = Devel::StackTrace->new;
    # Add other info to `$trace` object, or build error object/structure 
    # Print/log/etc  $trace (or your new error structure/object), or
    #die $trace;
}
```

The  `Devel::StackTrace` is of course useful also if you want to re-throw, in which case you can pass its object to `die`.  See docs, in particular the constructor options.

*A general warning: careful with `$SIG{__DIE__}`; it can be tricky. I'd say, better just use `Carp`.*

Finally, if by "*context*" you mean more detail from the call stack, you can walk the stack by hand using `caller` and retrieve lexicals from each frame by `PadWalker`.  An example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183690/46533790).

Comment: I somehow avoided `Carp` so far, but it seems to be the right tool for my problem, for the biggest part. Still, I don't see, how could I provide dynamic context for `$other_info` in die-handler? Like specific error-message for the function.

Comment: @w.k  `Carp` is definitely useful and _the_ tool for this, in principle.  OK -- so "_dynamic context_" and "_specific error-message_" -- what do you mean by that? What kind of things -- can you give me an example?

Comment: Like, I have initialized some basic data (`$base`) in a function to make a database query, but this database call dies. Now I need to form error-message based on `$base`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Padwalker` makes possible to look any lexical variable existed before `die`? Completely new tool for me.

Comment: @w.k Ah, OK, so scoop up any old variables you want (so to speak) ...  so, once a `die` is thrown, you can look at either 1) whatever is seen in the scope in which the handler is, or 2) go up the call stack and see all lexicals in each frame. (Only _in that call_'s stack.)  One example of precisely that is in the post linked at the very end.  (You can print things out of an `END` block as well, but that's really global.)

Comment: @w.k  If you really need more than this ... perhaps consider a full blown logging system, so there'd be plenty of info already logged whenever something goes down.

Comment: @zdim.. hello dear friend.. hope you are doing good!.. happy men's day!..

Comment: @stack0114106 hello hello -- very good to "see" you!!  :)  I hope all is very well with you :)

Comment: @stack0114106 ( I didn't even know about "men's day"!  ha!  :)

Comment: thank you.. now I'm moving towards clouds and containers..not able to spend time on SO..

Comment: @stack0114106 oh, OK -- that's interesting.  Yeah, SO (quietly) takes time.  It's been fun and I learned a lot but ... I reduced activity, and will reduce it further

Comment: yes.. me too!.. it has been a good learning in the past.. the work keeps me busy all the time.. cloud,containers, spark, etc...