# Modification of a read-only value attempted started appearing in script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to work out why this error is coming up in a Perl script:

```
A fatal error has occured:

    Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 7) line 10.

Please enable debugging in setup for more details.
```

When I run it with this from the command line:

```
perl -d admin.cgi
```

the point it dies is:

```
<p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>A fatal error has occured:</font></p><blockquote><pre>Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 14)[/home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/links/admin/GT/AutoLoader.pm:128] line 10.
</pre></blockquote><p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>Please enable debugging in setup for more details.</font></p>
Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 14)[/home/user/web/example.com/public_html/cgi-bin/links/admin/GT/AutoLoader.pm:128] line 10.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
```

Looking at the AutoLoader.pm file, I see this on line 128:

```
eval "package $pkg;\n#line $linenum$pkg\::$func\n$COMPILE->{$func}";
```

If I add in a bit more debug:

```
print "FOO: $pkg ($func)\n";
```

I then see this when running:

```
FOO: GT::Template (_call_func)
FOO: GT::CGI (html_escape)
FOO: GT::Base (in_eval)
<p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>A fatal error has occured:</font></p><blockquote><pre>Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 7) line 10.
</pre></blockquote><p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>Please enable debugging in setup for more details.</font></p>
Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 7) line 10.
```

The script worked fine the whole of yesterday, and I don't think I've changed anything that would cause this- so I'm at a bit of a loss.

**UPDATE:** After some more digging, I've found its coming from this line in another module:

```
my $output = $code->($self);
```

`$code` seems to be coming from a bit above:

```
my $root      = $self->{root};
my $full_file = $self->{root} . '/' . $template;
my ($code, $dont_save, $files) = $self->{opt}->{print} == 2
    ? @{$FILE_CACHE_PRINT{$full_file}}{qw/code dont_save files/}
    : @{$FILE_CACHE{$full_file}}{qw/code dont_save files/};
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
As requested, here is the output from `print STDERR qq|package $pkg;\n#line $linenum$pkg\::$func\n$COMPILE->{$func}\n|;`:

```
package GT::Base;
#line 538GT::Base::in_eval
sub in_eval {
# -------------------------------------------------------
# Current perl has a variable for it, old perl, we need to look
# through the stack trace. Ugh.
#
    my $ineval;
    if ($] >= 5.005 and !MOD_PERL) { $ineval = defined($^S) ? $^S : (stack_trace('GT::Base',1) =~ /\(eval\)/) }
    elsif (MOD_PERL) {
        my $stack = stack_trace('GT::Base', 1);
        $ineval = $stack =~ m{
            \(eval\)
            (?!
                \s+called\ at\s+
                (?:
                    /dev/null
                |
                    -e
                |
                    /\S*/(?:Apache2?|ModPerl)/(?:Registry(?:Cooker)?|PerlRun)\.pm
                |
                    PerlHandler\ subroutine\ `(?:Apache2?|ModPerl)::Registry
                )
            )
        }x;
    }
    else {
        my $stack = stack_trace('GT::Base', 1);
        $ineval   = $stack =~ /\(eval\)/;
    }
    return $ineval;
}


<p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>A fatal error has occured:</font></p><blockquote><pre>Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 7) line 10.
</pre></blockquote><p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>Please enable debugging in setup for more details.</font></p>
Modification of a read-only value attempted at (eval 7) line 10.
```

Comment: What is `GT::AutoLoader`? Is it your own library? That `eval` expression is odd, but I guess it should work. The error is presumably in whatever the `$COMPILE->{$func}` hash element expands to. Rather than printing individual variables, please print the string that is `eval`ed to make it clearer what is happening. `my $code = "package $pkg;\n#line $linenum$pkg\::$func\n$COMPILE->{$func}"; print "<<$code>>\n"; eval $code;`

Comment: @Borodin thanks - yeah it is weird, but it was working fine which is the oddest part. I've updated the question with the debug of `print qq|package $pkg;\n#line $linenum$pkg\::$func\n$COMPILE->{$func}\n|;`. Oh, and GT::AutoLoader is part of a script called `Gossamer Links` (not something I wrote)

Comment: Perhaps something in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183690/4653379) can help

Comment: There's no assignment in that code except to lexical variable `$ineval`. I think we're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Borodin yes maybe. I did comment a bit before, around `my $output = $code->($self);`. The error message really isn't that helpful with the location/line numbers either :(

Comment: @zdim thanks - the problem is that this is coming from the core modules (that were working fine). All the user front end is ok, its just this admin.cgi script that's being weird

Comment: If it were that `eval` then, because of the `#line` directive, the error message would say `... at GT::Base::in_eval line 538` (the line number will be higher). You need to find the code that is printing the error message (`eval` prints nothing on its own) and add a full stack trace so that you can see the call chain.

Comment: @Borodin - yeah - after digging deeper and deeper, I found that the Config file was updated by a script (see my answer below). It was trying to do: `FOO: (db_cgi_url) SCALAR(0x250d6e8)` - and the fact it was the SCALAR caused it to fatal on `$t->{"cfg_$key"} = $Links::IN->html_escape($val);` ... not the easiest thing to find! Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah man - found it! In the site config, it had this weird stuff going on:

```
'db_cgi_url' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url.' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url..' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url...' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url....' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url.....' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url......' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url.......' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url........' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url.........' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url..........' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
'db_cgi_url...........' => \'http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links',
```

Something somewhere else must be updating it, without me asking it to. The front end not under mod_perl seemed ok due to the fact it was using a cached version of Data.pm

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hah! Well done. Now you need to find *what* is updating the config

Comment: @Borodin yeah! I have a feeling its this from one of the scripts on our mobile version: `$CFG->{db_cgi_url} = "http://m.example.com/cgi-bin/links";`. Its a bit of a PITA, because if you update $CFG while a site build is going , mod_perl can cache it and then store the new variable (when you don't want it to). I think the reason we didn't have this problem on the old server, was because that script wasn't run under mod_perl (issues sending emails with sendmail, but this time we are using SMTP on the new server so don't have that problem)

Comment: @Borodin I'm just doing a test now and then going to do a build to see if it updates the Data.pm file again (incorrectly). If so, thats where the problem lies :)

Comment: @Borodin  - yup, that was it! Glad that was found. Not how I expected to spend my morning - oh the joys of coding! ;)